# hook_nodeapi() argument?

Tags: 6, hooks

[hook_nodeapi()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_nodeapi/6) only has four arguments, but the function `taxonomy_nodeapi($node, $op, $arg = 0)` can have an additional parameter, `$arg=0`. Why?
`$node` is not passed by reference. Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure how you're counting, but [hook_nodeapi()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_nodeapi/6) has 4 arguments, as you said, while [taxonomy_nodeapi()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--taxonomy--taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_nodeapi/6) has only 3. How they are named is totally irrelevant, only the amount and order counts. PHP doesn't have named arguments, you could also name them in your hook like this: `yourmodule_nodeapi($wathever, $you, $want = 0)` and it would work. There is however no reason to do it, it only has the potential of confusing someone. :)

The only important part is here is that the third and fourth argument are optional and must have a default value, because they are not passed for every `$op`.

About `&$node`, that's not so nice, but not a problem. The `&` can be left out, which means that `$node` is not by reference (in PHP4, that is) but it seems that `taxonomy_nodeapi()` doesn't need that. The other way round would be a problem in PHP 5.3 (adding a `&` here when PHP doesn't expect one).

Comment: but what's the $arg = 0 do? to the hook_node_api(), it is like as the parameter $a3? am i right?

Comment: It is the third argument of hook_nodeapi(), so yes, it's $a3. As I said, the name doesn't matter, only the order but it is confusing.

Comment: many thanks,taxonomy_nodeapi($node, $op, $arg = 0) .it told the taxonomy_nodeapi()body only effect on page. am i right?

Comment: @enjoylife No, it doesn't. The default value for the parameter is the value the function will use when the caller doesn't pass any value for that parameter. That means that if the caller passes `1` (or `TRUE`) as value for that parameter, the function will use that parameter, not `0`.

Answer (score 1):

The taxonomy_nodeapi is a implementation of [hook_nodeapi](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_nodeapi/6), so, it's supposed to support all available arguments. If you are implementing this hook in your custom module, be sure to check all supported arguments and its functionality.

Comment: i am sorry i don't know what's your meaning. the  hook_nodeapi don't has the argument $arg=0. and the node argument is passed by reference. but taxonomy_nodeapi($node, $op, $arg = 0) not.

Answer (score 1):

On your point about &$node and $node argument - they are not quite the same.

Although they do represent the node itself the presence of the ampersand (&) in the first argument means that it had been passed '**By Reference**', i.e. any changes made to the node object in your module/function will be preserved.

The argument without the ampersand has been passed '**By Value**' so while you can read any of the node values, you can't make any changes to the node itself (well you can but they will not be preserved outside of your module/function)

Also `$arg=0` is a default argument, if you do not provide a value for this then it will default to the value specified - in this case zero.

Comment: Yes, it is not the same. However, the difference doesn't matter in this case and the function definition is technically correct (although confusing and unnecessarily so). Leaving it away (in case of a hook implementation and assuming that it is not changed in that hook) in a case where the hook is documented with one doesn't lead to any errors, because PHP doesn't know that there should be one. The opposite, adding one where none is supposed to be leads to warnings in PHP 5.3 for hooks that are called with module_invoke_all()/call_user_func_array().

Comment: DilbertDave，what's the aim of the $arg=0? thank you.

Comment: @enjoylife: Check out example #3 at http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php for a better explanation

Comment: @Berdir: Agreed, not an issue in this case, but I thought I'd try to clarify ;-)